# Convergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac {e^{2ni}}{n\sqrt n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Does $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac {e^{2ni}}{n\sqrt n}$$

Converge?

What test would you use to study the convergence of this series?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\vert e^{in \theta} \vert = 1$. Hence, we have
$$\left \vert \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{in\theta}}{n\sqrt{n}}\right \vert \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left \vert e^{in\theta}\right \vert}{n\sqrt{n}} =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n\sqrt{n}} = \zeta(3/2)$$

Comment: Since part of the question asks which test to use, shouldn't you state it?

Comment: This uses the comparison test.

Comment: the comparison test is for positive summands. Surely you mean the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: @Tim Whatever name you call it.

Comment: I was trying to help. Your answer answers both questions only implicitly.